# Objective-C Protocol Madness -- how to return object based on protocol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

```
@protocol Eating
@end

@interface Eat : NSObject<Eating>
{
}
- (id<Eating> *)me;
@end

@implementation Eat
- (id<Eating> *)me { return self; }
@end
```

In the above piece of Objective-C code, why does "return self" result in a "Return from incompatible pointer type" warning? What's the incompatible pointer type and how to fix it?

Comment: Use @protocol Eating <NSObject> - it will let you use NSObject methods on those objects, rather than only methods you require.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `id` is a pointer itself, you don't need the asterisk.

```
@interface Eat : NSObject<Eating> {
}
- (id<Eating>)me;
@end
```

Comment: It's an asterisk, not an Asterix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix ;) (took me three times to get this comment right!)

Answer (score 2):

Okay .. answer is "id" instead of "id *".

Comment: Why downvote? He posted this as the first one because he figured the problem out himself.

Answer (score 1):

remove id * and replace with id. id is already a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Because `id` is essentially `NSObject *` (although there are some minor differences). Thus, when you return `self`, you are returning `-(NSObject *)`. What you have is `id *` which is like `NSObject **`.

Comment: `id` is a typedef for `struct objc_object*`, not `NSObject *`. The difference is significant.

Answer (score 0):

You are slightly off in your use - it's:

```
- (id<Eating>)me { return self; }
```

(because you are returning id, not a pointer to an object).

Comment: What's the difference between **a pointer to an object** and **id**?

Comment: Actually there is none - which is why your code did not work.  (NSObject *) and (id) are kind of already the same thing (not really but close enough for this discussion) so when you say (id *) it's like saying (NSObject **).  Yes it's a little weird that id and Class are both objects where you don't use the *...